# Using PHP Sessions to update content on another page

Tags: php, html

Just learnt about PHP sessions now need to learn how to use them properly. Can i declare all the variables on a seperate php document and then call them from my other pages? if so can someone show me a simple example.

Also note the snippet below that is in HTML

```html
<select id="baby_status">
  <option value="playing">Playing</option>
  <option value="awake">Awake</option>
  <option value="sleeping">Sleeping</option>
</select>
```

How will i use php to do for example: if baby `status = "awake"` when I click submit then display a picture of the baby being awake on page 2?

An explanation would be great but if someone can also show me what code to use it will also be great i am still learning.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can simply do this using $_POST

Your HTML code will look like this.

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
     <select name="baby_status">
        <option value="playing">Playing</option>
        <option value="awake">Awake</option>
        <option value="sleeping">Sleeping</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And your `page2.php` will look like this.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['baby_status'])) {
    $baby = $_POST['baby_status'];
    if ($baby == "awake") {
        echo '<img src="awaking_baby.png"/>';
    }
}
?>
```

If my answer worked for you don't forget to mark as correct. Because that will help other to solve there problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thats exactly what im looking for but why is the output this "'; } } ?> " on the web page?

Comment: Can you gave me the URL where are you try to execute my code.Thank you.

Comment: Im doing it locally using xampp

Comment: Right turning on Xampp might have helped this situation! right now it works this is great but it seems to only temporarily change the page value as long as its open? if i closed the form after updating the page would it go back to default

Comment: Yes so you can change the baby status when they are awake and the parents can view this then when they are asleep etc, hope im not causing too much trouble here aha, do you want to move this to discussion?

Comment: Where do you want to move this discussion?

Comment: Oh i need more reputation to chat.. but anywhere you know what your doing and it would be great to get your help.. maybe twitters instant messaging or something? just anything i can talk to you through if you want!

Comment: Do you use Hangouts. I think we should discuss in hangouts.

Comment: Yes whats your hangouts deets ill add you ^^ thanks a tonne btw

Comment: Hey ive added you on hangouts my names mckayze + ive left you a message!

Answer (score 1):

you can declare all the session value in login page and you can access that session value in any page first declare session value in a varible like below

```
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
```

and now you can use $useraname any where untill you logout

Comment: Awesomes, thats put some clarification on the first bit now just need to know how to use it for the second and most important part of what im doing

Answer (score 0):

So you'd have your form like so:

```
<form action='session.php' method='post'>
    <select id="baby_status" name="status">
        <option value="playing">Playing</option>
        <option value="awake">Awake</option>
        <option value="sleeping">Sleeping</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Then at the action location you'd setup your session....

```
<?php session_start();

    //Add the post data to the browser session
    $_SESSION['status'] = $_POST['status']; 

    //...and do what you want now with $_POST['status']

?>
```

Now on subsequent php scripts all you have to do is...

```
<?php session_start();
    $status = $_SESSION['status'];

    //or ensure it's set first...
    $status = (isset($_SESSION['status'])) ? $_SESSION['status'] : false;

    if($status !== false){
        echo "<img src='path/to/file/${status}.jpg' />";
    }
    else{
        echo "<img src='path/to/file/default.jpg' />";
    }

?>
```